# How do i use the output from a definition for the input for another definition in Python

Tags: python

So i want to use the output from deF rot5 which is "fff" as the input for 
def rot5_inverse. And then i want it to output the output the same way like i dit in def rot5.

My textbook says it should work but i can't get it to work.

```
print("rot5")
aaa = "aaa"
def rot5(string):
   alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
   retstr = ""
   for i in  string:
       index = alphabet.index(i)
       retstr = retstr + alphabet[(index+5) % 26]
   print(retstr)
rot5(aaa)


print("")
print("")

def rot5_inverse(string):
   alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
   retstr = ""
   for i in  string:
       index = alphabet.index(i)
       retstr = retstr + alphabet[(index+21) % 26]
   print(retstr)
rot5_inverse(rot5(string)
```

use the output from def rot5 as input for def rot5_Inverse and output the result of rot5_inverse

the code should give the expected output according to my textbook but the error that i get is

> "name 'string' is not defined"

Comment: I get different error: `NameError: name 'text' is not defined`. However, `string` in your context may be referring to the [string library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html)

Comment: @davedwards i accidentally pasted text there it should be string i fixed it now in the question. thanks for pointing that out to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your last line you call `rot5_inverse(rot5(string)`:

- Your `string` variable is not yet defined. If you want to use the word string you have to call it with `rot5_inverse(rot5('string'))`, else you need to declare string, i.e. `string = 'aaa'`
- You're missing a closing bracket

Comment: now in the def rot5_inverse i get this error in the `for i in string` line                                > "'NoneType' object is not iterable"

Comment: Yes -- because you passed `None` into the function -- that's the return value from `rot5`.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you adopt incremental programming -- you've tried to write a two-phase main program and two non-trivial functions, doing all of that before you tested to see whether any of your code works.  Write a few lines at a time; test that much.  Don't write more until you've debugged those few.  Right now, you have enough errors that you're getting tangled in the weeds.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but I have corrected your code as per my understanding of what you want! Hope it helps you understand python!

```
 print("rot5")
 aaa = "aaa"
 your_string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

 def rot5(alphabet):
    retstr = ""
    for i in alphabet:
        index = alphabet.index(i)
        retstr = retstr + alphabet[(index+5) % len(alphabet)]
    return retstr

 def rot5_inverse(alphabet):
    retstr = ""
    for i in alphabet:
        index = alphabet.index(i)
        retstr = retstr + alphabet[(index+21) % len(alphabet)]
    return retstr

 rot5(aaa)
 print("")
 print("")
 print(rot5_inverse(rot5(your_string)))
```